# Can I use sendmail and mailx procedures in ubuntu installed in HYPER-V

Tags: ubuntu, sendmail, hyper-v, mailx

I have installed Ubuntu 14 LTS inside HYPER-V (Windows 8.1) . 
Installed mailutils and sendmail using apt-get.
But I am not able to send mail using neither programs. 
connections and everything are correct , something I have configure in windows 8.1 or sendmail/mailx ?

Regards,
Lavish

Answer (score 0):

Use the following test scripts to send email messages in verbose mode to diagnose your problem.

The script below should be executed by non `root` user:

```
#!/bin/sh
# send test email as normal (non root) user
# change RECIPIENT to valid email address
RECIPIENT=john.doe@example.net
/usr/sbin/sendmail -i -v $RECIPIENT <<END
subject: test email (non root)

test
END
```

The script below should be executed by `root` user:

```
#!/bin/sh
# send test email as privileged (root) user
# change RECIPIENT to valid email address
RECIPIENT=john.doe@example.net
/usr/sbin/sendmail -Am -i -v $RECIPIENT <<END
subject: test email (root)

test
END
```